# How to use Netgear WGT624v3 as a wireless bridge?

Tags: router, wireless-bridge

I would like to use my router as a wireless bridge.  I think this is most simplified by installing the Tomato firmware on the router.  I followed [this guide](http://petescrap.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/using-netgear-wgt624v3-as-a-wireless-bridge/) to put Tomato on my router and it failed.

Does anyone have this router and got it to work as a wireless bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable *any* wifi-router to act as a wireless bridge simply disable the DHCP service (aka *Distribute IP Addresses*) and do not connect the WAN port.